# Symfony2 long polling on SSL server

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, long-polling

I have an Symfony2 application that has a long pooling mechanism implemented. The user logs in the application, and at a certain time a long pooling request is started to notify the user about some changes while he still works inside the application.

The php session is saved in the database so no session locking problems occur while opening other ajax requests during the long pooling duration.

After installing a SSL certificate the problems appeared and the long pooling seems to lock other requests while he is running, behaving like the normal php session. Although the php session is still saved/read from the database the application behaves like a locking mechanism is present and doesn't allow two request at the same time.

Is this a problem with configuring the SSL module or am I missing something about Symfony's behavior? If I disable the SSL everything works great and multiple requests at the same time are not a problem.

Late edit:

Apparently the problem was with the HTTP2 headers. If I use HTTP2 headers concurrent requests are queued and executed one after the other. Using HTTP1.1 everything is ok. This is really strange, because I checked the server config according to apache documentation and this should work with my SSL module. Anyone has experienced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Are doing it with jQuery or Angular, from the client ? If so, check JS console and  debug network. Also, can you get an hand on the SSL apache conf of your server ? Some parameters may overload the default config of your server, and makes conflict with the working non-ssl config.

Comment: I am using ExtJS 5.1 for the application. There are no errors on the console, nor on the server. Also the only difference between the old SSL config of the server and the new one is the path to the certificate file and this:
`<IfModule http2_module>
ProtocolsHonorOrder On
Protocols http/1.1 h2
</IfModule>`

Comment: OK that would be very unexpected if path to certificate or protocols order management influences your issue... I cant see what would provoke this. Have you check the apache logs ? did you try to remove the ProtocolsHonorOder ? we never know....;

Comment: Apparently removing h2 from protocols did the job. I still need to read on why this is happening, but for the time being I will use only Protocols h2c http/1.1